# php artisan commands not working for jailed user

Tags: linux, shell, php, jails

I jailed a user using jail-shell from github (https://github.com/pymumu/jail-shell). The user has php binaries. So the php command works. But when I execute php artisan commands like 'php artisan serve' or 'php artisan optimize:clear' from that user's terminal, I get fatal error as shown below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "config" does not exist in /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:912
Stack trace:
#0 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(912): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(795): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#2 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(933): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array, true)
#3 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(731): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('config', Array)
#4 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(918): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#5 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1454): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config')
#6 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(544): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('config')
#7 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(595): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->getDefaultDriver()
#8 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(124): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->parseDriver(NULL)
#9 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(665): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver()
#10 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(287): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error('Call to undefin...', Array)
#11 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(250): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->reportThrowable(Object(Error))
#12 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(522): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#13 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Error))
#14 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 {main}

Next Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [config] does not exist. in /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:914
Stack trace:
#0 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(795): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#1 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(933): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array, true)
#2 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(731): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('config', Array)
#3 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(918): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#4 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1454): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config')
#5 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(544): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('config')
#6 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(595): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->getDefaultDriver()
#7 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(124): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->parseDriver(NULL)
#8 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(665): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver()
#9 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(287): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error('Call to undefin...', Array)
#10 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(250): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->reportThrowable(Object(Error))
#11 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(522): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#12 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Error))
#13 /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 {main}
  thrown in /home/salman/public_html/your-project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 914
```

I faced this issue in almalinux 8, centos and ubuntu 18 but not in ubuntu 20. Is there any file or env variables that the jailed user is missing?